# How can I remove address element highlighting when I double click using the chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code block and javascript that work as intended.

```
<li>
  <a id="menuPrev">
    <div class="sprite-blank"></div>
  </a>
</li>

$('#menuPrev')
  .click(function () {
     ...
     return false;
  })
  .doubleClick(function() {
     return false;
  });
```

When a user double clicks on the address link a blue line appears below the `<a>` element a the bottom of the `<li>` element. This only happens with the Chrome browser and on a double click. From what I can see it's the default color behaviour in Chrome when I double click on something. It looks confusing and if possible I would like to stop this happening.

So far I have found that if I change the code and add href="#" to the link then this
does not happen. However when I do this the link address appears at the bottom of 
the page and I don't want this.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this and make the browser ignore my 
double clicking?

Comment: Can you provide an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where the problem manifests? My first guess would be, that it's `outline`-related.

Comment: I think @phant0m is right. It's either the outline, or since you're double clicking, it could be that the element is selected, and you're seeing the selection highlighting. If the latter, there are CSS `user-select` properties that can disable user selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `href="javascript:void(0);"` to prevent browser from displaying the link in the status bar.

Also try `event.preventDefault();` to "as the name suggests"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already solved it, you just need to prevent the browser from displaying the link in the status bar. The first thing you have is a link with no href. Chrome flat out just doesn't like this because it considers the link to be malformed. So you should place your `href="#"` back in place and add this to your jQuery:

```
$('#menuPrev')
  .click(function () {
     ...
     return false;
  })
  .doubleClick(function() {
     return false;
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
     window.status = '';
  });
```

Comment: I don't think he meant the link being displayed in the status bar. "`When a user double clicks on the address link a blue line appears below the <a> element a the bottom of the <li> element`"

Comment: @phant0m: Yes, the fix for that is to include an href attribute in the element (as is proper for any anchor). That is the true solution. OP's subsequent problem was: `However when I do this the link address appears at the bottom of the page and I don't want this.` This is where the status bar comes into play.

Comment: I can't imagine why Chrome would consider an `<a>` element without an `href` to be "malformed".

Comment: Oh, I have to admit I have not read that far. Personally, I hate sites that hide the links from me.

Comment: @user1689607: "Malformed" is perhaps in imprecise term. In this context I'm using it describe the nature of a link vs a placeholder. Chrome treats them differently, though I'm not sure about the specifics of placeholder display in Chrome honestly.